# Rails unitialized constant error in many to many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many

I am trying to create a relationship in which a user can have many orders and many products, an order can have many products but belong to one user, and a product can have many users and many orders.

So far I have the below code, with the three aforementioned models plus a join table. The issue I am having is that whenever I try accessing `user.products` for example, I get an `uninitialized constant Order::ProductOrder` error, or if I try `product.orders` I get `uninitialized constant Product::Orders`.

Would anyone be so kind as to lend their experience towards solving this problem?

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :product_orders
  has_many :products, through: :product_orders
end
```

---

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :product_orders, class_name: 'ProductOrders'
  has_many :orders, through: :product_orders
  has_many :users, through: :orders
end
```

---

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders
  has_many :products, through: :orders
end
```

---

```
class ProductOrders < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :orders
  belongs_to :products
end
```

**DB Schema:**

```
  create_table "orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "fulfilled_date"
    t.integer "quantity"
    t.integer "total"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_orders_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "product_orders", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "product_id"
    t.bigint "order_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_product_orders_on_order_id"
    t.index ["product_id"], name: "index_product_orders_on_product_id"
  end

  create_table "products", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "image_url"
    t.string "name"
    t.string "description"
    t.integer "inventory", default: 0
    t.integer "price"
    t.bigint "order_id"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.index ["order_id"], name: "index_products_on_order_id"
    t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_products_on_user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.string "address"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "zip"
    t.string "phone_number"
    t.string "country"
  end
```

Comment: what is the file name of ProductOrders? Also in `order.rb`, you may need to add class_name for has_many :product_orders

Comment: also, in `ProductOrders`, it should be singular `:order` and `:product` instead of plural.

Comment: according to rails conventions, model names are usually singular - ideally have been `ProductOrder` rather than `ProductOrders`. This would have saved you from explicitly telling `class_name` everywhere.

Comment: @kiddorails `product_orders.rb`. Adding the class name like so didn't change anything unfortunately `has_many :product_orders, class_name: 'ProductOrders'`

EDIT: Sorry, didn't see your other comments. Trying it now.

Comment: @kiddorails Thanks! I guess it was just changing to `:order` and `:product` in `ProductOrder` that fixed it because I did previously have `ProductOrder` instead of `ProductOrders`.

Comment: great. added as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of corrections needed:

add `class_name` for `:product_orders` in `Order`;

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :product_orders, class_name: 'ProductOrders'
  has_many :products, through: :product_orders
end
```

`belongs_to` should have singular `order` and `product`:

```
class ProductOrders < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product
end
```